# Jquery hover and display back the full title

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently create a toggle div, when the div not hover the long title will automatically show `...` for the rest characters more than 30, So far I have successfully created the `...` function .

I need when hover the div the long title will show exactly the long title full text.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6g30t07/1/)

**JS**

```
     $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').hide();



 $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(function (index, currentText) {
     var newText = currentText.substr(0, 30);
     if (currentText.length > 30) newText += "...";

     return newText;
 });

 $("#popup_survey_whitebox").hover(function () {
     $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop().animate({
         opacity: 1,
         height: "toggle"
     }, 500, function () {
         // Animation complete.
     }).css('position', 'relative');



     $("#popup_survey_end_whitebox").click(function () {
         $("#popup_survey_whitebox").remove();
     });

 });
```

For example :

full text long title : **testingtestingtestingtestingtesting123**

long title : **testingtestingtestingtestingtesting...**

when hover it show **testingtestingtestingtestingtesting123**

mouseout: **testingtestingtestingtestingtesting...** again

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @caleb.breckon I need when hover the div the long title will show exactly the long title full text.

Comment: Can you edit your jsfiddle with meaningful data? eg. change the text of your long title to something like "This is the long title."

Answer (score 1):

You have to cache your text like this:

```
 $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').hide();

 var orig = '', // create var to cache the original text
     newText = ''; // create var to cache the new Text with "..."

 $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(function (index, currentText) {
     orig = currentText;
     newText = currentText.substr(0, 30);

     if (currentText.length > 30) newText += "...";

     return newText;
 });

 $("#popup_survey_whitebox").hover(function () {
     $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop().animate({
         opacity: 1,
         height: "toggle"
     }, 500, function () {
         $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(orig); // Here put the original text.
     }).css('position', 'relative');

 }, function () {
     $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop().animate({
         opacity: 1,
         height: "toggle"
     }, 500, function () {
         $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(newText); // Here put the new text with "..."
     }).css('position', 'relative');
 });

 $("#popup_survey_end_whitebox").click(function () {
     $("#popup_survey_whitebox").remove();
 });
```

### [Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/t6g30t07/2/)

---

The syntax is this:

```
$(elem).hover(fn, fn);
```

first `fn` gets executed when you hover the element and second `fn` is executed when you mouse out of the element. it is just mouseenter, mouseleave.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer ! But now when I move to a function it doesn't work anymore. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qnhcudp/1/), please take a look . Thanks